# How to include types of my private repo in the public repo bundle of monorepo?

Tags: typescript, types, publish, monorepo

I currently use yarn pnp & workspace for my monorepo.

And, I made a `@types` repository to share the types in my repositories.

However, this `@types` repository is private, i wanna publish them with my public repository.

For example, I exported `@types` in my public library repo.

```
// @types/index.ts
export enum BUTTON_TAG {
  BUTTON = "button",
  ANCHOR = "a",
}
export type ButtonTag = `${BUTTON_TAG}`;
```

```
// my-public-library/index.ts
export * from "@types";
```

But my bundle does not includes @types. I'm worried that users won't be able import these types when my library is published.